# Paypal Integration in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to integrate paypal now into phonegap. I am using the example show here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

My exact code is as follows. I am using phonegap build. So what I did was create an index.html that has the following code in it

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="author" content="e" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/icons.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/component.css" />
        <script src="../../js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
                <button id="buyNowBtn" onclick="dopayment();"> Buy Now </button>
        </div>
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/my-app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index_paypal.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                //start paypal
                var clientIDs = {
    "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID", // not needed while testing
    "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "my id which i am ommiting"
  };
  window.PayPalMobile.init(
    clientIDs,
    onPayPalMobileInit // callback, configured below
  );

function onPayPalMobileInit () {window.PayPalMobile.prepareToRender("PayPalEnvironmentSandbox", // or "PayPalEnvironmentProduction" for production mode
new PayPalConfiguration({
      // for more options see js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js
      merchantName: "Telerik Test Shop",
      acceptCreditCards: true,
      merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: "https://mytestshop.com/policy",
      merchantUserAgreementURL: "https://mytestshop.com/agreement"
    }),
    function() {console.log("OK, ready to accept payments!")}
  );

  function dopayment(){
    var paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(
  "15.00", // subtotal (amount ex shipping and tax)
   "3.00", // shipping
   "2.00"  // tax
);

var payment = new PayPalPayment(
  "20.00", // amount (the sum of the fields above)
  "USD",   // currency (in ISO 4217 format)
  "Telerik T-Shirt", // description of the payment
  "Sale",  // Sale (immediate payment) or Auth (authorization only)
  paymentDetails // the object prepared above, optional
);
window.PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(
  payment,
  function(payment) {alert("payment success: " + JSON.stringify(payment))},
  function(errorresult) {alert(errorresult)}
);
  } 

                //end paypal


                });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My idea is for the dopayment funtion to run when I click the button. The exact example i referenced toesn't run either thought. I am not sure exactly what more i need to do